# Blender 2.8 animate color gradient - export to glTF

Tags: blender, gltf

I would like to export an animated gradient to glTF 2.0 in Blender 2.8. Does that work? 
Unfortunately, I can only get a monochrome export with the glTF Metallic Roughness component.
I created the animated color gradient with the help of a Colorramp.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow!  This question would be better placed on the [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).  But unfortunately, glTF 2.0 does not include any animated materials at this time.  There's been some interest in developing an extension for animated materials, but none have appeared so far.

Comment: Belongs in Blender Stack Exchange. (comment added to explain 'close' vote)